# How to identify pass-by-value or pass-by reference in Java?

Tags: java

Please pardon the beginner question.I met this code fragment on the internet:

```
public class Person {

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    StringBuffer a = new StringBuffer("A");
    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer("B");
    operate(a,b);
    System.out.println(a+","+b);
}


static void operate(StringBuffer x, StringBuffer y)
{
    y.append(x);
    y=x;

 }
}
```

I figured out the running output should be A,A, however, the correct output should be A,BA, could expert help me understand why the value of b is still AB? Why "y.append(x)" will affect the value of b, but not "y=x"? That is where I am getting confused.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try putting more *actual information* into the *title* instead of just "help me understand". The title this way is completely useless!

Comment: Technically, Java always passes **by value**. For everything but primitive objects, it passes a reference "by value".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that Java arguments are passed by value, so the final assignment in `operate` doesn't have any effect.

The detailed sequence of events is as follows:

1. `a` and `b` are initialized to two StringBuffer objects.  Lets write this as

   ```
    a -> S1{"A"}
    b -> S2("B")
   ```
2. The (trivial) argument expressions for the `operator` call arguments are evaluated giving S1{"A"} and S2{"B"}.
3. The call starts, and the two references are assigned to the local variables `x`  and `y`.  So the state is now:

   ```
    a -> S1{"A"}
    x -> |

    b -> S2("B")
    y -> |
   ```
4. The `y.append(x)` call modifies the S2 object:

   ```
    a -> S1{"A"}
    x -> |

    b -> S2("BA")
    y -> |
   ```
5. The `y = x;` assignment is performed:

   ```
    a -> S1{"A"}
    x -> |
    y -> |

    b -> S2("BA")
   ```
6. The `operate` method returns, causing `x` and `y` to go out of scope.

   ```
    a -> S1{"A"}
    b -> S2("BA")
   ```

The key thing to note is that in step 5 we DID NOT change the contents of the S2 object.  Instead, we just changed `y` to refer to the other object.

Comment: thanks. My only question is in step 4, why "y.append(x)" modifies S2 but "y=x" doesn't modify S2?

Comment: The answer is that that is the way that Java assignment works with reference types; i.e. objects and arrays.  You are assigning the reference, not the copying the contents of the thing on the RHS over the contents of the thing on the LHS.

Answer (score 0):

In the method, the `y=x` line only change the local variable `y` and doesn't impact the `b` variable in the caller scope.

Changing the `b` variable in the operate method, as you can't pass pointers to variables in java is a bit harder. You could either :

- return it : `b = operate...`
- change its content (but that would be a copy)

Comment: Then why does y.append(x) will affect b? It is still in the local method operate(),

Comment: It doesn't affect the variable, but the object that is passed (and to which a reference is kept in the outer scope).

Answer (score 0):

Java does not use **call by name** or **call by reference**.

```
void replace(Anything x) {
  x = y;
}
```

does nothing, **by definition**, as `x` is a *new* variable, not an alias for the calling variable. Any changes to the variable `x` are confined to the method scope. Note that `x.setSomething` may still modify the *contents* of what `x` references.

This actually applies to most programming languages. It avoids errors, and there are ways to achieve the desired result explicitly.

Java always does **call by value**. Even when using references, they are technically passed as values (of type object reference).

I.e. a variable "`Integer example;`" is technically not an `Integer`, but it is a reference (which could be `null`) to an `Integer` instance. The *reference* is copied (call by value), but of course it still references the same object afterwards. So you can modify the object, but you cannot change the actual reference, as you only have a copy of it.

Comment: I think you mean "Java does not use **call by reference**".  As far as I know, there has only ever been one programming language that used true **call by name**, and that was Algol-60.

Comment: C/C++ preprocessor macros are also very close (although not "true" I guess) call by name.

Answer (score 0):

Lets dry-run the operate method:

1. The reference states are 
   `a -> A, x -> A, b -> B, y -> B.`
2. `append` executes 
   `a -> A, x -> A, b -> BA, y -> BA.`
3. `y=x` executes
   `a -> A, x -> A, b -> BA, y -> A.`

Now, What should be the print output? :-)

The gist is,

### Java is Pass-By-Value

.